# How can I sort arrays alphabetically by using the second element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, explode

Would appreciate any help with this.:)

I have the following text file:

```
roomA     Springer, Jerry    js@email.com
roomB     Cruise, Tom        tc@email.com
roomC     Jovi, Bon          bj@email.com
```

and I want to sort it by the surname so it outputs:

```
Cruise, Tom      roomB        tc@email.com
Jovi, Bon        roomC        bj@email.com
Springer, Jerry  roomA        js@email.com
```

I know how to load the file:

```
$a = file("details.txt");
```

and think I have to use explode() to split up the data (tab-seperated):

```
$array = explode("\t", $a);
```

this makes the name the second element in the array.

How do I put the string back together with the name coming first, followed by the room and email?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `var_dump($array)` and it will display you the indexes. You then only need to swap two elements with each other. Here is a trick:

```
list($array[0], $array[1]) = array($array[1], $array[0]);
```

After that, you can [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) the result as you did `explode` it:

```
$line = implode("\t", $array);
```

Hope this is helpful. Ah well, and for sorting, take a look at [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort).

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't the best tool for this job.

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $2"\t"$1"\t"$3}' infile | sort > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is not in a know format that i know .. the `tabs` and `space` between them are not constant ;

*** Do not use in production .. i had to hack my way around ***

Try

```
$note  = "roomA     Springer, Jerry    js@email.com
roomB     Cruise, Tom        tc@email.com
roomC     Jovi, Bon          bj@email.com";

$data = array();
$info = explode("\n", $note);

echo"<pre>" ;
foreach($info as $line)
{
    $words = preg_split("/\\s/", $line);
    $words = array_filter($words); // remove spaces
    $words = array_values($words); // To reset the keys 
    $data[$words[1] . $words[2]] = $words[1] . $words[2] ."\t" . trim($words[0]) . "\t" . trim($words[3]) .  "\n";
}

asort($data); //Sorting the data ;
print_r(array_values($data));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cruise,Tom   roomB   tc@email.com

    [1] => Jovi,Bon roomC   bj@email.com

    [2] => Springer,Jerry   roomA   js@email.com

)
```

**Advice**

Use standard formats suvh as `csv`, `json` or `xml`

I would try improving it with preg_match